# iOS Safari Won't Refresh Javascript Content

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, reload

I just created this [Awesome Website](https://jongwoo-lee.web.app/about) with some interactions, but I found a bug on iOS Safari about the 'Firebase' Animation (it won't work). So I connected my iPhone(iPhone 6, iOS 12) to my Mac with a cable to use the Safari Web Inspector.

But then even when I reload the page or open it again, the JavaScript content won't reload. However, on desktop browsers, the changes have been applied.

The bad thing is that I'm a student and there's this stupid thing about screen time that blocks private mode and history&cache delete.

I really need to fix this bug and there's a bunch of other bugs to fix, so probably waiting until the page fully reloads will drive me nuts. Is there any way to do a 'hard' reload, or is there any other ways to fetch data from the server again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer.

Connect the iPhone to your Mac via USB cable, open the web inspector, then press ⌥⌘R.

The keyboard shortcut also works for iOS safari.